# How do I get the states to exist in unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

This is the config file for the routes.

```
module SalesDashboard.Administration.Routing {

"use strict";

class RoutingConfig {

    static $inject = ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider"];

    constructor($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider.
            state("main", {
                url: "/index.html"
            }).
            state("home", {
                url: "/administration/home",
                templateUrl: "components/home/home.html"
            });

       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/administration/home");
    }
}

angular
    .module("SalesDashboard.Administration")
    .config(RoutingConfig)
    .run(["$rootScope", "$log", ($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $log: ng.ILogService) => {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateNotFound", (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) => {
            $log.log(event);
            $log.log(error);
        });
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) => {
            $log.log(event);
            $log.log(error);
        });
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) => {
            $log.log(event);
            $log.log(error);
        });
    }]);
}
```

This is the spec file

```
describe("SalesDashboard.Administration.Routing.RoutingConfig", (): void => {

    var $httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService;
    var $q: ng.IQService;
    var $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService;
    var $state: ng.ui.IState;
    var $stateService: ng.ui.IStateService;
    var $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService;
    var $location: ng.ILocationService;
    var $templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService;

    beforeEach(() => {

        angular.mock.module(($provide: ng.auto.IProvideService): void => {
            $provide.constant("APP_LANG", { someUrl: "en-US" });
        });

        angular.mock.module("SalesDashboard.Administration");

        inject(($injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService): void => {
            $httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend") as ng.IHttpBackendService;
            $q = $injector.get("$q") as ng.IQService;
            $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope") as ng.IRootScopeService;
            $state = $injector.get("$state") as ng.ui.IState;
            $stateService = $injector.get("$state") as ng.ui.IStateService;
            $timeout = $injector.get("$timeout") as ng.ITimeoutService;
            $templateCache = $injector.get("$templateCache") as ng.ITemplateCacheService;
            $location = $injector.get("$location") as ng.ILocationService;
        });

        $httpBackend.when("GET", "/assets/languages/locale-en-us.json").respond(null);
    });
        // some tests
    });
```

The issue I'm having is when running my tests, none of the states exist and I can't figure out for the life of me why not. If I execute $stateService.go("main"), I get error message **Could not resolve 'main' from state ''**. The big question is: how do I get my states config to exist within the context of my tests?

Comment: Sounds to me like your are not unit testing? Here you are injecting the real implementations of your dependencies, i.e. integration testing. Instead use jasmine or alike to mock out the calls you expect so you dont run the actual implementations.